# Editing an ArrayList in onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist, touch-event

I'm writing an Android application with the following basic structure:

`MyActivity.java` - sets view as `MyView`.

`MyThread.java` - contains `surfaceHolder`, calls `update()` and `render()` functions in `MyView.java`

`MyView.java` - draws to canvas using `render()` function, updates `MyPuzzle` class, handles touch events.

`MyPuzzle.java` - contains an `ArrayList/Vector` of elements.

My question is:

In the `MyView` class, in the `render()` function I loop through the contents of the `ArrayList/Vector` held within the `MyPuzzle` class and draw them to the canvas. However, I was occasionally getting `indexOutOfBounds` errors (perhaps once every 10 times), despite looping from `i=0; i<arraylist.size()...`

In the same `MyView` class, in the `onTouchEvent` function, I have code which adds/removes items from the `ArrayList/Vector` which is being drawn.

Are my index out of bounds errors likely caused by the `onTouchEvent`s being processed at the same time as the `render()` function is looping through the `ArrayList/Vector` and drawing the elements to the screen?

I tried implementing a system whereby the `onTouchEvent`s were not dealt with immediately, but were added to an `ArrayList` queue, and only processed before `render()` is called. This seems to have fixed the problem, with the limited testing I've done of it. Does this sound about right? It's been driving me somewhat mad.

Thanks for your help in advance, apologies for the badly written question, I can add any more detail you may require.

Comment: Can we have the code where you are getting the error? It would help us help you help us all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IndexOutOfBounds is probably a direct result of a situation where the iterating thread will intially see the List at size N and starting iterating from 0 to N.  Thread-2 Comes in and removes from the list making it effectively N-1, so if Thread-1 attempts to read at list.get(N) you get your exception.

If the depth of the list isn't very large and you are not removing and adding a whole lost swap the List implementation with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.  Otherwise you will need to `synchronize` on all actions of the list including the iterating for example

```
public void render(){
  synchronized(list){
    for(int i =0; i <list.size();i++){
      //....
    }
  }
}
public void update(Object element){
 synchronized(list){
  list.remove(element);  
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it definitely makes sense to me. My ArrayList isn't particularly large, it typically has around 30 relatively simple objects in. At most I tend to swap/remove one or two elements on each update, so I assume using CopyOnWriteArrayList would be okay here? Cheers again.

Comment: No problem!  CopyOnWriteArrayList should be fine!